# Onclick tag on achor tag doesn't work anymore?

Tags: hyperlink, onclick, anchor

I want to add second tag for same anchor tag. I was using this code few months ago but now it doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
 <a class="hesperiidae" href="#hesper" onclick="location.href='#hesper1'"><b>H</b></a>
```

These tags are for same page. It was working fine few months ago, I have no idea what changed. Is there any other alternative? Like in this example, how can I summon #hesper1?

Comment: onclick="location.href='#hesper'"

Comment: try it without the 1

Comment: Doesn't work. I just cannot summon the second tag anymore. Suppose it is not #hesper1 and is #xyz. How can I summon #xyz?

Comment: Dolev Dublon Is there any other way to add an alternative #tag besides onclick="location.href""?

Comment: Make a screen recording video and explain your problem more specific so i can tell u exactly what is the bug

Comment: Upload the video to YouTube

Comment: Show me a tag that works the way u want and show me the problem with this tag

Comment: Sure sir, here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMYASnT6an8

Comment: i need to see the url of the browser but it looks like U dont understand how to develop

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/html-tags-continued/pt/html-links

Comment: check this tutorial  and try to make a website follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0bGHP-PXD4

Comment: I'd be very glad if you could help me regarding this particular issue.